# What is: "jquery1413396620463='6'"

Tags: javascript, html

Odd question, I know. I'm looking at the html source of a page in a site that was migrated from 2007 to 2013. The HTML source has this odd jquery attribute in many places, such as  tags.  One  tag has 15 of these values:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' jquery133485837484593="6" jquery43758475847584="6", jquery43758475847683="6" etc.
```

Any idea what these are? It seems like something that would be generated, not hand-coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the jQuery expando attribute, it's a bit random because it's generated on page load, it's "jQuery" + (new Date()).getTime() (to avoid possible naming conflicts) but you'll notice the attribute is the same for all elements.

This is they key in $.cache for the element's events and data...it's stored this way for a few reasons, the main is to avoid circular references. The ID is actually $.uuid which is just an incrementing counter used for each element's key in $.cache.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922441/what-is-the-meaning-of-jquery-random-attributes-in-html-expando-attribute

Comment: Thanks! Is there a sharepoint feature that uses this OOB? Is this custom functionality that someone has added?

Comment: Check your master page, it seems your site is using jQuery and there are some custom JavaScript getting executed on page load.